# Phase correlation for rotation registration using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, rotation

I'm trying to register two images that are a rotated and translated version of one another using opencv. Generally speaking, the procedure is (pseudo code):

a. **IF1** = FFT2(**I1**); **IF2** = FFT2(**I2**)

b. **R_translation** = (**IF1**).*(**IF2_conjugate**)

c. **R_translation** = **R_translation**./abs(**R_translation**)

d. **r_translation** = IFFT2(**R_translation**)

where the maximum of **r_translation** corresponds to the translation. Moving on to calculate the rotation, the abs value removes the translation part,

e. **IF1_abs** = abs(**IF1**); **IF2_abs** = abs(**IF2**)

Converting to Linear-Polar coordinates,

f. **IF1_abs_pol** = LINPOL(**IF1_abs**); **IF2_abs_pol** = LINPOL(**IF2_abs**)

f. **IFF1** = FFT2(**IF1_abs_pol**); **IFF2** = FFT2(**IF2_abs_pol**)

f. **R_rot** = (**IFF1**).*(**IFF2_conjugate**)

c. **R_rot** = **R_rot**./abs(**R_rot**)

d. **r_rot** = IFFT2(**R_rot**)

where the maximum of **r_rotationn** corresponds to the rotation. While for translation alone, the cv2.phaseCorrelate function returns expected results, for rotation, it returns odd results. So I had tried the following.

I took two numpy.array-s 5x5, which are a rotated version of one another like so:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
a = a.astype('float')/a.astype('float').max()
b = numpy.array([[5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
b = b.astype('float') / b.astype('float').max()
```

First I calculated the phase correlation myself:

```
center_x = numpy.floor(a.shape[0] / 2.0)#the x center of rotation (= x center of image) 
center_y = numpy.floor(a.shape[1] / 2.0)#the y center of rotation (= y center of image)
Mvalue = a.shape[1] / numpy.sqrt(
    ((a.shape[0] / 2.0) ** 2.0) + ((a.shape[1] / 2.0) ** 2.0))  # rotation radius
```

Calculating the FFT, taking the absolute value (losing the translation difference data if existed), and switching to Linear-Polar coordinates and normalizing:

```
a_polar = cv2.linearPolar(numpy.abs(numpy.fft.fft2(a)), (center_x, center_y), Mvalue, cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
b_polar = cv2.linearPolar(numpy.abs(numpy.fft.fft2(b)), (center_x, center_y), Mvalue, cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
a_polar = a_polar/a_polar.max()
b_polar = b_polar / b_polar.max()
```

Another FFT step, multiplying point wise, and IFFT back:

```
aff = numpy.fft.fft2(a_polar)
bff = numpy.fft.fft2(b_polar)

R = aff * numpy.ma.conjugate(bff)
R = R / numpy.absolute(R)
r = numpy.fft.ifft2(R).real
r = r/r.max()
```

yields,
[Phase correlation for rotation, **b** with respect to **a**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdufu.png)

According to cv2.linearPolar() the rows, span the angle (in this case with step size of 360/5 = 72degrees) and the columns span the radius (from 0 to the maximum radius given in Mvalue. The maximum is evident at the last row (corresponding to approximately -90degree shift). So far so good..

The second method is using cv2.phaseCorrelate() directly,

```
r_direct = cv2.phaseCorrelate(a_polar, b_polar)
```

which yields,

[Phase correlation for rotation, **b** with respect to **a** direct method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6AQq.png)

The first tuple, is the X,Y correlation coefficient (in pixels?) and the third number is the fit grade. When it is close to unity, the correlation coefficient represents better the data (the blob around the maximum is more distinct).

Other than the fact that the result is not distinct enough (why?), the result is confusing...

Generally, The first FFT process in this 5x5 example was not necessary. If rotation is the only interference, one can immediately switch to Linear-Polar coordinates and use cv2.phaseCorrelate. In that case, the result is also confusing.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

David

Comment: Check my implementation, it on CPP, but in bottom of readme there is a link to python version I used as a base, implementations are differs a bit. https://github.com/Smorodov/LogPolarFFTTemplateMatcher

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems similar to my code (swapping real with abs and adding a FFTSHIFT). Altering my code that way caused it to not function properly. My main question is regarding the opencv function phaseCorrelate which suppose to produce a quick result.